# Call controller and action from custom middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET 5 and the middleware classes. What I'm trying to create is a middleware class that reads incoming URL requests. Based on that I either want to let it go through and do a normal Route lookup, or I want my middleware class to call a specific controller/action from my Web API class.

What I currently have is the following. I think the comments in the code explains what I'm trying to achieve.

```
public class RouteMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RouteMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if(httpContext.Request.QueryString.Value == "test")
        {
            // Call custom Controller / Action
            // Then, don't do any more route resolving, since we already have the right controller/action
        }
        else
        {
            // Continue like normal
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this in my middleware class?

Comment: Why not let the routing engine does it job let it route the request to your desired controller using attribute routes?

Comment: @HenkMollema Mostly for learning purposes. I just want to know how to create routes dynamically from middleware. Can come in handy when I want to load controllers from another assembly / class library. Like from a class library that has its own middleware and Controller class.

Comment: you can create a redirect response.

Answer (score 1):

I think one way of doing this is by having own implementation of IRouter.
Here is what I did as a test to have my own RouteHandler and it worked well for me.

1. Added [MvcRouteHandler](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e38493842570eb9940ec9519fa22f70f74726d50/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/MvcRouteHandler.cs) and [MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/48bfdceea6d243c5ec8d6e00f450f8fe7cce59f7/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs) in my project.
2. Used `Mynamespace.MvcRouteHandler` in `UseMvc` method of `MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions` and renamed the method to `UseMyMvc`.

   ```
   public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyMvc(this IApplicationBuilder app,Action<IRouteBuilder> configureRoutes)
       {
           MvcServicesHelper.ThrowIfMvcNotRegistered(app.ApplicationServices);
           var routes = new RouteBuilder
           {
               DefaultHandler = new MyNamespace.MvcRouteHandler(),
               ServiceProvider = app.ApplicationServices
           };
        //..... rest of the code of this method here...
       }
   ```
3. In Startup.cs, changed `app.UseMvc` to `app.UseMyMvc`
4. Then in `RouteAsync` method of `MyNamespace.MvcRouteHandler`, set controller and action based on custom logic.

   ```
     context.RouteData.Values["area"] = "MyArea";
     context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "MyController";
     context.RouteData.Values["action"] = "MyAction";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't answering the question, but it sounds to me like you want a custom route handler:
http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing
https://luisfsgoncalves.wordpress.com/2015/07/29/asp-net-5-routing-part-i/
https://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/custom-routing-aspnet5-mvc6